# LeetCode - 2. Add Two Numbers

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm attempting to address Leetcode problem [2. Add Two Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/):

> You are given two **non-empty** linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in **reverse order**, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I've implemented a solution that seems to work for most cases, but it fails for specific scenarios. Here's the provided code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        num1 = 0
        num2 = 0
        while l1:
            num1 = (num1*10) + int(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        while l2:
            num2 = (num2*10) + int(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
        res = num1 + num2
        dummy = ListNode()
        n = dummy
        for i in range(len(str(res))):
            n.next = ListNode(res % 10)
            res = res // 10
            n = n.next
        return dummy.next
```

It successfully handles general cases, but when tested with inputs like `l1 = [2,4,9]` and `l2 = [5,6,4,9]`, the output is `[8,9,8,5]`, while the expected result is `[7,0,4,0,1]`.

My strategy is to accumulate the values from the linked lists, calculate their sum, and then create a new linked list to store the result. I've observed other solutions that use different approaches, but I'm unsure why my current implementation is failing in certain scenarios.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is not a homework help site exactly, and we're not all on LeetCode, so you'll need to explain what you're trying to accomplish. Check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to [step through your code to help debug](/q/4929251/4518341)

Comment: Have you checked out `itertools.zip_longest()`?

Comment: The point of this exercise may have been per-digit computation & "manual" carry handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first part of your function. The numerical value you get from a list is wrong, because the list has the *least* significant digit in its head node, and then the more significant digits in the other nodes. Your code interprets the first node has having the *most* significant digit.

In the second part of your function, you do it correctly: the new list that you create will have the least significant digit in its first node, ...etc.

Here is a function that correctly gets the value that is represented by a linked list:

```
class Solution:
    def valueof(self, node):
        power = 1
        num = 0
        while node:
            num += node.val * power
            power *= 10
            node = node.next
        return num
```

Now you can do:

```
        res = self.valueof(l1) + self.valueof(l2)
```

...and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The test cases given here are the numbers in reverse order, that means the test case here is

l1 = [2,4,9] representing number   942

l2 = [5,6,4,9] representing number 9465

the sum of these both numbers is 942 + 9465 = 10407 which is represented in list as [7,0,4,0,1].
In first loop you are trying to accumulate number in reverse order i.e value of num1 is 249 and value of num2 is 5649 and res is sum of both which is 5898.

You need to reverse the list before accumulating values from it or else you need to reverse the accumulated value for getting correct answer.